# Shaded region on screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Why I am getting the shaded region in my screen, I have put the Linear layout inside Relative layout.

Here is my xml corresponds to this screen

[image: I am grtting the shaded region in backround of buttons,I want to remove that shaded region... How to remove that]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/bg"

       android:id="@+id/mainlayout">

   <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="175dip"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:background="@drawable/trans"
      android:id="@+id/innerlayoutmain"

      >

       <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="35dip" 
       android:id="@+id/sleepEasilyMeditationButton1"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
       android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
       android:text="Sleep Easily Meditation"
       ></ImageButton>

       <ImageButton
       android:paddingTop="10dip"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="25dip" 
       android:id="@+id/howToUseButton1"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
       android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
       android:text="How to Use This App"
       ></ImageButton>

       <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="25dip" 
       android:id="@+id/aboutShazzileandAliButton1"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
       android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
       android:text="Abount Shazzie and Ali"
       ></ImageButton>

       <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="25dip" 
       android:id="@+id/divinityPublishingHomeButton1"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
       android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
       android:text="Divinity Publishing Home"
       ></ImageButton>


       <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="25dip" 
       android:id="@+id/shareThisAppButton1"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
       android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
       android:text="Share This App"
       ></ImageButton>
       </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

I am getting shaded region on screen.

I put linear layout inside relative layout.

I have changed screen resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following modification in your code.

In xml file:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

and in your java file:

```
ImageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you used:

```
android:background="@drawable/trans"
```

in the linear layout.
If you don't want, you can remove this line. Or, if you want a different color You can change it.

Comment: i removed that statement from xml file, but it does not works

Comment: IN java code are you using  LinearLayout ll = findViewById(); then next ll.setBackground(Some value); if yes then remove this line in code also i.e ll.setBackground.

Comment: @Suraj Shinde : Clean and build your project and then run again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
android:background="@drawable/trans"
```

Use this:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: android:background="@android:color/transparent" I tried this also ,but it does not works